# Wordpress user system for reporting

Tags: wordpress, file-upload

I'm looking to create a system in Wordpress (or find a similar plugin, perhaps) that allows a user on my Wordpress to see a unique report PDF link, which will be different for each user and that the reports shown can be controlled through the admin panel.

So for example, there's USER A and USER B, they both have separate logins, however ADMIN A can upload a report.pdf for USER A and a separate one for USER B and they can see their report on the front-end.

Does anyone have any ideas, plugin or otherwise?

Comment: what kind of reports do you mean by that? or is it just a file that the admin needs to upload?

Comment: Sorry I should have stated, yeah; it's just a file that the admin can upload to each individual account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin that will allow you to do exactly what you are asking. It is called user files https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-files/